# How do I check if there is nothing typed in a lua string?

Tags: string, lua

Seems to always output false no matter what the Text is.

```
function onClick()
    if Main.UsernameInput.Text or Main.PasswordInput.Text == '' then
        print("false")
    else print("true")
        Main.Visible = false
    end
end
```

Comment: That's not quite how an if-statement and or-operator works. Each statement separate by or (or indeed and) will need to be evaluated separately. Like so: `if value1 == '' or value2 == '' then`.

Comment: so it should be like this?

function onClick()
if Main.UsernameInput.Text == '' or Main.PasswordInput.Text == '' then
    print("false")
else print("true")
    Main.Visible = false
end
end

Comment: That looks more correct, yes.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @cj89898: What application are you using? The API arouses my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onClick()
    if Main.UsernameInput.Text == '' or Main.PasswordInput.Text == '' then
        print("false")
    else print("true")
        Main.Visible = false
    end
end
```

The or operator checks to see if the conditional on the right is true, if it is it goes on with your statement.

If the left is false, it will then check the right side, if it's true, then it will continue on.

Now if you want to check to make sure BOTH of the sides are true then use the and operator as such:

```
if Main.UsernameInput.Text == '' and Main.PasswordInput.Text == '' then
```